# template alias causes unit test failure

Tags: unit-testing, templates, d

I'm a freshfaced D newbie and I'm very interested in exploiting all that it has to offer. I'm currently in the process of turning a large codebase I have in C++ into D for education. I've barely started though and I'm reaching some weird inconsistency. I have a template struct with a constructor and a unittest for that constructor, (hope i'm using it right). It seems to verify correctly. However, if I make a type alias at the bottom of the file to a specific templated struct, I get an exception within the unittest.

main.d

```d
import math;

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

math.d

```d
import std.math;
import std.stdio;

struct Vector2(T) {
    T[2] vec = [0, 0];

    @property const T x() {return vec[0];}
    @property inout(T) x(inout(T) val) {return vec[0] = val;}
    @property const T y() {return vec[1];}
    @property inout(T) y(inout(T) val) {return vec[1] = val;}

    this(T x, T y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    unittest {
        Vector2!int a = Vector2!int(2, 2);
        assert(a.x == 2 && a.y == 2);

        Vector2!float b = Vector2!float(2.2, 2.2);
        assert(b.x == 2.2 && b.y == 2.2);  // <-- this line excepts given alias
    }
}

// if this is not here, no problem.
// if it is here "core.exception.AssertError@math.d(21): unittest failure"
alias Vector2f = Vector2!float;
```

why does the presence of an alias cause a unit test to fail? I am using this command to build:

```
dmd -unittest main.d math.d
```

I use Windows 10, DMD version 2.070.2, and msys2 shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A template itself is not (and in general, cannot be) unittested. Only its instantiated instances are.
2. Since `2.2` cannot be exactly represented in a floating-point variable, the `double` closest to `2.2` is not the same as the `float` closest to `2.2`. If you change the lines to the following (`2.2f` is a float constant, `2.2` is a double constant), the test succeeds just fine:

   ```
       Vector2!float b = Vector2!float(2.2f, 2.2f);
       assert(b.x == 2.2f && b.y == 2.2f);  // <-- no exception
   ```

Generally, one should avoid comparing floating-point variables directly unless they [really know what they are doing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768). In D, one may want to use [std.math.approxEqual](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_math.html#.approxEqual) to compare them.

Comment: Makes sense. So this unit test will be ran once for each instantiation of the template that appears in my code? For example if in main i make a Vector2!int and a Vector2!float the unittest will be ran twice? So to unit test a template like this, should I place that unit test outside the struct? Also, does this mean that creating an alias causes the template to be instantiated?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis You are right, the unittest you got belongs to the module scope. A unittest at template scope is ran for every instantiation. It _looks like_ every alias means an instantiation, but I don't have a hard proof in the spec at hand.

Comment: good point on the comparison of floats, I will definitely give that paper a read.

Answer (score 3):

A template is not even compiled beyond some basic syntax checking if it's not instantiated. A templated type is a *template* for a type, not an actual type. So, `Vector2` is not a type, whereas `Vector2!int` is. The fact that you declared the alias to `Vector2!float` is what instantiated `Vector2` and caused it to be fully compiled - including the `unittest` block. A `unittest` block inside of a template doesn't get compiled anymore than the rest of the template if the template is not instantiated, and it will be compiled into each instance of the template (which is why it's generally not a good idea to put `unittest` blocks inside of templates).

So, at minimum, you should put a `unittest` block outside of the template which instantiates the template. If you want to avoid compiling the unit tests into each instantiation of the template, then you should just move them all outside of the template (presumably marked with comments to indicate which functions they go with), and that will cause the template to be appropriately instantiated and tested. If you don't care about having a copy of the unit tests with each instantiation of the template and want to leave the tests immediately after the functions that they test (like you normally would), then you just need to put a `unittest` block after the template which instantiates it at once so that the `unittest` blocks inside of the template get compiled in and run.

There is [a proposal](http://wiki.dlang.org/DIP82) for adding a feature to allow for special `unittest` blocks inside of templates which are not actually part of the template and function like a `unittest` block outside of the template would function (but would still be next to the functions being tested), but it's not yet decided whether it or something like it will be added to the language to fix this problem. So, in the interim, I'd advise against putting `unittest` blocks inside of templates, but regardless, you need to make sure that a template is instantiated outside of itself in order for it to be compiled and tested.

On a side note, you really shouldn't ever compare floating point values with `==` or `!=` as  explained in this classic paper: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Using [`approxEqual`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_math.html#.approxEqual) would be a much better choice.